# Magento 2 Customer Api Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

I have added a custom attribute say `child_first_name` to customer entity. When I try to access through rest API, I can able to get the attribute in the result-

```
snip..
    {
     "custom_attributes": [   {
          "attribute_code": "child_first_name",
          "value": "No name for student"
       }]
    }
```

However is it possible to group custom attributes like address in the api result. For example-

```
snip..
       {
         "child_info": [   {
              "child_first_name": "some name"
           }]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. The API uses that form so that the schema (keys) are always known and predictable, even if the data itself varies. This isn't particularly significant for REST/JSON, but it's very significant for SOAP (XML), which has a pregenerated WSDL defining the schema.